# Use automapper to update destination object and set nullable type property value to null

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-2

It seems that nullable type properties in source is ignored and not copied to destination.

Consider these classes:

```cs
public class Source 
{
    public int? Test { get; set; }
}

public class Destination 
{
    public int? Test { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>();

var source = new Source() { Test = 1 };
var destination = new Destination();

Mapper.Map<Source, Destination>(source, destination);

Assert.AreEqual(source.Test, destination.Test); //true

source.Test = null;

Mapper.Map<Source, Destination>(source, destination);

Assert.AreEqual(source.Test, destination.Test); //false (null, 1)
```

It worked when I used:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
    .ForMember(m => m.Test, o => o.ResolveUsing(m => m.Test));
```

But I don't want to set that per property, can you set that globally? Or is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Seems that creating maps for each nullable type to itself like:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<int?, int?>()
    .ConvertUsing(v => v);
```

Seems to work as a fix. But I would rather have a complete solution with all nullable types then specifiyng them one by one. Easy to miss something.

Comment: thanks. this solved my problem. this seems like an automapper bug to me though.